# How can I find a application or service on the local network?

Tags: network-programming, local-network

I have two sprig-boot applications running on two different computers within the same local network.

I need to make a rest request from application 'A' to application 'B'. The computers can reboot, so the internal ip addresses can change. In conditions when there is no internal static ip - application 'A' doesn't know to which ip to make a request.

What are some modern (or not modern) solutions to this problem? Maybe we should run a script together with applications that would make ip addresses static. Maybe there is some method of searching for an application/service in the local network by name or something like that?

Comment: Look for `multicast`.